# Absolute positioning of children with respect to parent and viewport

Tags: jquery, css

```
    <div class="parent">
    <strong>I function as a hover trigger</strong>
    <div class="child">I am a child</div>
    </div>

    ... // More number of <div> Skipping for reducing the number of lines

    <div class="parent">
    <strong>I function as a hover trigger</strong>
    <div class="child">I am a child</div>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
.parent{
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top:0;
    right:148px;
}
```

The Script

```
$('.parent').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).find('.child').css({"display": "block"});
});
$('.parent').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).find('.child').css({"display": "none"});
});
```

The child `<div>` will appear if the parent `<div>` is hovered. And the position of child is with respect to the parent. But how can the position is adjusted such that if the child overflows the viewport it needs to be pushed up. Usually the child corresponding to the top parent `<div>` does not overflow from the viewport whereas the children of the bottom parent `<div>` get overflow.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use jQuery, you can simply calculate the needed offset

```js
$('.parent').mouseenter(function(e) {
    var $child = $(this).find('.child');
    $child.css({"display": "block"});
    var offset = $child.offset();
    if (offset.top + $child.height() > $(window).height()) {
        var top = $child.height() - $(this).height();
        $child.css({'top': '-' + top + 'px'});
    }
});
```

This looks, if the bottom of the child overflows the viewport and shifts the child the needed offset higher.

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bW272/)

Comment: Will this work in IE? My IE version is 11 and seems the child does not appear. But working as expected in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I'm on Linux, so I cannot comment on IE.

Comment: Yeah okay. And in IE the child appears with jQuery version 1.9.1 and does not with 1.10.1.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can set and `if` statement calculating if the child element overflows the viewport like this:

```
//Calculate the height of the window
var wh = $(window).height();

//Begin Hover function
$('.parent').hover(function(e) {

//Calculate height of child and position from the top of viewport
  var ch = $(this).find('.child').outerHeight(),
      ct = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
      diff = ch + ct;

//If that value are more than window height then change position of children
    if (diff > wh) {
        $(this).find('.child').css({'top':'auto','bottom':'0'}) 
    }
  $(this).find('.child').css({"display": "block"});

}, function(e) {
  $(this).find('.child').css({"display": "none"});

//Remove position after leave parent
  $(this).find('.child').attr('style','');
});
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/P7NPd/2/